# NSTextField get default margin dimensions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I`ve got several programmatically created `NSTextField`-s, used as static text controls. The algorithm that creates them sets their dimensions via `setFrame:` and assumes that they have zero padding between the text and the upper right corner of the control, which is not the case, so the text is getting clipped.

At first I began researching the topic of zero padding for `NSTextField`-s but quickly realized that this approach requires subclassing. It would be much easier for me than that if I could just use some method to obtain the padding dimensions and adjust the bounding rectangle accordingly.

My question is: what`s the name of that method?

[UPD:] Seems to be [`alignmentRectInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1526870-alignmentrectinsets?language=objc), however it`s not available on macOS 10.6 — so I`d like to know if there is a similar method for 10.6.

Comment: What is macOS 10.6?  That's Snow Leopard.  You are still using it?

Comment: @ElTomato Yup. Not using daily, but still testing my apps for compatibility. Is that wrong? (Well, it might be, as I`m not much into Apple community, I just know that my ex has an MBP with 10.6 installed, so I also keep it installed on a VM)

Comment: Try to look here (Font metrics) https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html

Comment: @MarekH My font metrics are correct. I\`m using [CoreText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1478566-ctframesettersuggestframesizewit?language=objc), checked nearly a dozen trickier cases manually in GIMP.

Comment: @hidefromkgb It's great that you have that range of OS support, but with the adoption rate Apple tends to have combined with the fact that macOS updates are free, you're probably safe to drop some of the older OSes. Additionally, you're going to gain a lot of potential for new functionality as well as performance improvements from newer versions of Xcode and its compiler.

Comment: Can't you use `cellSize` or `sizeToFit`?

Comment: @Willeke I can, sure, but I\`d like to avoid subclassing here.

Comment: Why do you need subclassing to call `cellSize` or `sizeToFit`?

Comment: @Willeke I thought you suggested to redefine these two. Well, after some sleep I understand I was wrong.